# Creating Dynamic Sitemap in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, dynamic, sitemap

I have developed a publishing portal in sharepoint.I have a requirement wherein I need to create sitemap for the entire web application.

This should be dynamic, in the sense, whenever we update the contents of any given page in our web application, it should be reflected immediately in the sitemap page. What are the possible ways to achieve this and which is the best possible solution considering the scalability and easy configuration?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use a custom webpart, you could use normal navigation list to create your sitemap and it is automatically updated. You only need to style it in a way to resemble some kind of sitemap.

Here are some links to get you started with customizing your navigation:

- [Custom Navigation in SharePoint - The Full Monty](https://web.archive.org/web/20160306080422/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/modonovan/archive/2008/05/30/custom-navigation-in-sharepoint-the-full-monty.aspx)
- [How to: Customize Navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms558975%28v=office.14%29)

Also there is the [portal site map](https://web.archive.org/web/20130605145354/http://office.microsoft.com:80/en-au/sharepoint-server-help/about-the-portal-site-map-HA001160567.aspx) which provides the data source for your custom menu. Just read up on custom navigation and stuff like `PublishingNavigation:PortalSiteMapDataSource` and `SharePoint:AspMenu`.

There is a nice PowerShell script to create a sitemap for SHarepoint 2010, if you want to submit your sitemap to Google: [Generate A Sitemap For SharePoint 2010 Using PowerShell'](http://www.glynblogs.com/2010/07/generate-a-sitemap-for-sharepoint-2010-using-powershell.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can also install and customize the SharePoint Web part ("Table of Contents") to your liking.  [Read up on it here...](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/use-the-table-of-contents-web-part-to-display-navigation-on-a-web-page-HA010167419.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at our ECS product, it is close to what you need
http://www.infowisesolutions.com/product.aspx?id=ECS

It was built as a system of cross site collection navigation, with security trimming and permissions inheritance between site collection.